# Cocoa: react to keyDown in QLPreviewPanel

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, keydown, quicklook

I implemented quick look in my project in the following way in Swift 2 (I'm including this here for reference and because it might help someone else set it up).

My NSViewController contains a NSTableView subclass where I implemented `keyDown` to listen to the spacebar key being pressed (maybe not the best way but it works):

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let s   =   theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers!
    let s1  =   s.unicodeScalars
    let s2  =   s1[s1.startIndex].value
    let s3  =   Int(s2)
    if s3 == Int(" ".utf16.first!) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(NSNotification(name: "MyTableViewSpacebar", object: nil))
        return
    }
    super.keyDown(theEvent)
}
```

In my view controller, I have an observer for this notification and the functions required by the `QLPreviewPanel`:

```
//...
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: MyTableView!
    var files = [FilesListData]() //array of custom class
    //...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //...

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "spaceBarKeyDown:", name: "MyTableViewSpacebar", object: nil)
    }

    func spaceBarKeyDown(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let panel = QLPreviewPanel.sharedPreviewPanel() {
            panel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }

    override func acceptsPreviewPanelControl(panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func beginPreviewPanelControl(panel: QLPreviewPanel!) {
        panel.delegate = self
        panel.dataSource = self
    }

    override func endPreviewPanelControl(panel: QLPreviewPanel!) {
    }

}

extension ViewController: QLPreviewPanelDataSource {
    func numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewPanel(panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Int {
        return self.myTableView.selectedRowIndexes.count
    }

    func previewPanel(panel: QLPreviewPanel!, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem! {
        if self.myTableView.selectedRow != -1 {
            var items = [QLPreviewItem]()

            let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            for i in self.myTableView.selectedRowIndexes {
                let path = self.files[i].path //path to a MP3 file
                if manager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
                    items.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                } else {
                    items.append(qm_url) //image of a question mark used as placeholder
                }
            }

            return items[index]
        } else {
            return qm_url //image of a question mark used as placeholder
        }
    }
}
```

**What I would like to do now** is listen to the keys "up arrow" and "down arrow" being pressed while the quick look panel is open, in order to change the selected row in the `NSTableView`, much like **Finder** behaves when you preview files with quick look. I have no clue as to how I could implement this. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found what I was looking for and it's actually pretty simple.

Since my main view controller is also my delegate for the QLPreviewPanel, I added this:

```
extension ViewController: QLPreviewPanelDelegate {
    func previewPanel(panel: QLPreviewPanel!, handleEvent event: NSEvent!) -> Bool {
        let kc = event.keyCode
        if (kc == 126 || kc == 125) { //up and down arrows
            if event.type == NSEventType.KeyDown {
                self.myTableView.keyDown(event) //send the event to the table
            } else if event.type == NSEventType.KeyUp {
                self.myTableView.keyUp(event)
            }
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Then in my table view delegate:

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard myTableView.numberOfSelectedRows > 0 else {
        if let panel = QLPreviewPanel.sharedPreviewPanel() {
            if panel.visible {
                panel.close()
            }
        }
        return
    }

    if let panel = QLPreviewPanel.sharedPreviewPanel() {
        if panel.visible {
            panel.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

That's it! The `QLPreviewPanelDataSource` handles the rest.